# Magento Navigation Bar Edit - RWD theme

Tags: magento, navigation

I'm wondering if someone knows how I can make the navigation bar in Magento look like the below without a module? or if anyone knows of a free module to do the same job?

Using version 1.9.2.2.

What it currently looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN3uk.jpg

What I want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWaAB.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: It's a lot more preferable if you post the images themselves, rather than links to the images. Also, have you researched it? Found anything out?

Comment: Hi David, 

I have tried googling for my specific needs but I just haven't had any luck. I've found modules which can do what I want but ideally I don't want to spend a penny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot's of free module for this.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-exploded-menu.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mega-menu-best-navigation-extension.html